# Can't do a CTAS when I use dbname in CTAS

Tags: hive

A piculiarity I noticed.

When I try

```
create table dbname.table_name as select
```

I get `Error creating temporary folder on: hdfs://nameservice1/apps/hive/warehouse. Error encountered near token 'TOK_TMP_FILE'`

But If I first do

```
use dbname;
```

and then

```
create table table_name as select
```

It works. Why is that?

Comment: Hive version? ...

Comment: @Dudu Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create table in any database user need to have write permission on current database and database in which table is being created.

I.e. while running `create table dbname.table_name as select` statement , you need to have write permission on current database as well.

This is known issue reported in jira `HIVE-11427`.